Capturing the current source location and std::format_args for a compile-time checked log function
At a high level, what I want to achieve is a member log function with the same prototype as std::print that also captures the source location i.e.:
// possible output: "file.cc:22: some format args"
my_logger.info("some {} args", "format");

This can be solved quite neatly as shown in this answer to a very similar question.
The problem is that I also want compile-time checked format strings, so I don't want to fall back onto std::string_view to store the format string and punt format errors to the runtime. This means the format_string_with_location has to be generic over Args... in order to store std::format_string<Args...>.
What I came up with so far is the following:
template <typename... Args>
struct format_string_with_location {
   consteval format_string_with_location(
       std::format_string<Args...> fmt,
       std::source_location location = std::source_location::current()) noexcept
    : format{fmt},
      location{location}
  {
  }

  std::format_string<Args...> format;
  std::source_location location;
};

template <typename... Args>
format_string_with_location(char const*) -> format_string_with_location<Args...>;

export class logger {
public:
  template<class... Args>
  void info(format_string_with_location<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
  {
    std::println(fmt.format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};


Now this fails because at the call site, the compiler sees const char* as the format string and it cannot make the jump to format_string_with_location despite my (attempt at a) deduction guide. I assume this is due to the template arguments not being connected in any way to the to-be-deducted const char* parameter:
logging.cxx:28:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'format_string_with_location<Args...>' against 'const char *'
   28 |   void info(format_string_with_location<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
      |        ^
logging_test.cxx:124:13: error: no matching member function for call to 'info'
  124 |         log.info("Log me");

I have seen workarounds that would turn the info() function into a template <typename... Args> struct info so the constructor for that struct receives both the format string and args parameters, helping the compiler deduct the correct type, but this doesn't work here because it's a member function.
This is using C++23 on Clang 19, but a possible solution should compile on all C++23 compliant compilers. If there is some upcoming super-experimental C++26 things that help with this, I'm also fine with that, as long as it's standard C++.
Am I tilting at windmills and should just punt type checking to the runtime, or is this solvable in some way?

You probably want format_string_with_location<std::type_identity_t<Args>...> fmt (in logger) to disallow type deduction (which failed).

That works beautifully, thank you! If you want to make that a proper answer, I'll go ahead and accept that.

With
export class logger {
public:
  template<class... Args>
  void info(format_string_with_location<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args);
};

Args should be deduced (identically) from format_string_with_location<Args...> and Args&&...
In addition Args cannot be deduced from CTAD from const char*.
You should removed unneeded CTAD, and you might make some argument non-deducible:
export class logger {
public:
  template<class... Args>
  void info(format_string_with_location<std::type_identity_t<Args>...> fmt, Args&&... args)
  {
    std::println(fmt.format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};


Just a suggestion to invert the placement of the type_identity_t.
If you look at the way that this is specified in [format], you'll see that we have:
// [format.fmt.string], class template basic_format_string
template<class charT, class... Args>
  struct basic_format_string;

template<class... Args>
  using format_string = basic_format_string<char, type_identity_t<Args>...>;
template<class... Args>
  using wformat_string = basic_format_string<wchar_t, type_identity_t<Args>...>;

That is, format_string<Args...> is already itself a non-deduced argument. Which makes the usage of it quite nice - you don't have to worry about it:
template <class... Args>
void log(format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args); // just works

So you should do something similar (note that I'm also fixing your constructor, which was otherwise not viable):
namespace impl {
    template <class... Args>
    struct format_string_with_location {
        template <class T> requires std::constructible_from<std::format_string<Args...>, T const&>
        consteval format_string_with_location(T const& fmt,
                                              std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
            : fmt(fmt), loc(loc) { }

        std::format_string<Args...> fmt;
        std::source_location loc;
    };
}

template <typename... Args>
using format_string_with_location = impl::format_string_with_location<type_identity_t<Args>...>;

Which then allows the usage you originally wanted:
export class logger {
public:
  template<class... Args>
  void info(format_string_with_location<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
  {
    std::println(fmt.format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

How you actually differentiate between the two names (the alias template that you use in your signatures and the class template that actually implements this) is up to you.
Demo.

I like it, thank you for the suggestion. This keeps the signatures a bit cleaner and less boilerplatey.

Your demo prints [/app/example.cpp:8] and [/app/example.cpp:25] is expected!

Fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/aocxKoeK7
